# Non deterministic Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, non-deterministic

I am new to NDTM, but I do understand the concept of a turing machine. when it comes to NDTM I get a little confused, I m supposed to develop a NDTM for language {a,b,c} and

```
L = {w ∈ Σ*| Ǝv ∈ Σ*, Ǝn >= 2 with w = v (to the power of) n }
```

First thing that I want to know is how to read L, for example what is the meaning of Ǝ.
I do understand that a NDTM gives twp possibilities of one outcome, like for example for a:
we would have with a and without a if i am correct, Can someone help me fugure this out?

Comment: Is this really on-topic for SO? That statement is [set-builder notation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html) in mathematics. It basically says that L is the set of w's in Sigma* where there is also a v in Sigma* such that w = v^n, where n>=2. And to answer at least one of your questions, the backwards E basically reads "there exists" or "there is one".

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist isnt it the same as w must have the length which is the multiple of 2? well I though here you can ask any sort of question regarding computer topics!!

Comment: @S.N StackOverflow is for specific programming-related questions only.

Comment: No, it's not the same as that at all. If Sigma* was the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` then L would be `{1, 2, 3}` because it is basically asking you to give it every member of the set that has _a power of that member (squared or better)_ also in the set. It has nothing to do with even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be marked as "Homework" I think.

`Ǝ` is "there exists"
`Σ` is "the set of symbols in the language" (`{a, b,c}`) in this case
`∈` is "element of"

Now that we have that, we can read this language.  So `L` is the set of words `w` in `{a, b, c}*` such that there exists a word `v` and there exists a `n >= 2` such that `w` is a repetition of `v` `n` times.  E.g. `ababab = (ab)^3 ∈ L`.

Now you want to come up with a Turing machine, `M`, to represent this language, so you have to consider:

- When do we reject a word (what is our rejection state, what is on the stack)
- When do we accept a word (what is our accepting state, what is on the stack)
- How do we guarantee that `M` terminates.

We can see that `a` is not in `L` because `n >= 2` which implies that the length of `v^n` is at least `2` (`0` in the case of the empty string though, which is an outlier).  Similarly for `b` and `c`.  With that consideration and the knowledge that `n >= 2`, figure out what words are not accepted (e.g. consider `b`, `abc`, `cab`, `cca`, etc.).